# Loop through databases to get INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that I need to run for a handful of databases:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%zip%';
```

Is there some notion of iterating through a list of strings, and using a variable that I can substitute into a `USE` statement?

```
my_dbs = ['test_db', 'live_db', 'dev_copy_db']

?? For each db in my_dbs: ??
    USE @db;
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%zip%';
```

Or is there a way to look at all databases by default, instead of just `master`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sql-server, there's 'sp_MSforeachdb'.  It will loop through all databases on the server for you.  Inside it, you can use dynamic sql and pump the data into a temp table created outside of it.

```
create table #columnDatas (
    dbase_name sysname,
    table_name sysname,
    data_type sysname,
    column_name sysname
);

exec sp_MSforeachdb '

    use     [?]

    insert  #columnDatas 
    select  ''?'', table_name, data_type, column_name
    from    information_schema.columns
    where   column_name like ''%zip%'';

';

select * from #columnDatas
```

**UPDATE:** Version utilizing sys.databases

Thank you to Sean Lange who points to issues with sp_MSforeachdb skipping databases.  So here's another version, still dynamic, that loops sys.databases instead:

```
declare @columnDatas table (
    dbase_name sysname,
    table_name sysname,
    data_type sysname,
    column_name sysname
);

declare @template nvarchar(max) = '
    select  ''@db'', table_name, data_type, column_name
    from    [@db].information_schema.columns
    where   column_name like ''%zip%''
';

declare 
    @dbid int = 5, -- ignore system databases
    @maxDbid int = (select max(database_id) from sys.databases);

while @dbid <= @maxDbid 
begin

    declare @db sysname = (
        select  name 
        from    sys.databases 
        where   database_id = @dbid
    );

    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = replace(@template, '@db', @db);
    insert @columnDatas exec (@sql);
    set @dbid += 1;

end

select * from @columnDatas;
```

Comment: Be careful using this approach. The undocumented sp_msforeachdb will sometimes skip databases. It is really kind of nasty. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange.  I gave an alternate that omits its use.

Answer (score 1):

To do this dynamically is certainly possible. But with just 3 databases it is easier to code and test by just writing it out. This will retrieve the information you requested on those three databases in a single pass. I also added the database name so you know where it came from.

```
SELECT DatabaseName = 'test_db'
    , TABLE_NAME
    , DATA_TYPE
    , COLUMN_NAME
FROM test_db.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%zip%'

UNION ALL

SELECT DatabaseName = 'live_db'
    , TABLE_NAME
    , DATA_TYPE
    , COLUMN_NAME
FROM live_db.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%zip%'

UNION ALL

SELECT DatabaseName = 'dev_copy_db'
    , TABLE_NAME
    , DATA_TYPE
    , COLUMN_NAME
FROM dev_copy_db.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%zip%'
```

If this needs to be a more dynamic solution it will require some dynamic sql to do this. Not a huge deal but more effort than it is worth for 3 databases.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Undocumented system stored procedure **sp_MSforeachdb**
2. Cursor over sys.databases

Option 1:
Undocumented system stored procedure **sp_MSforeachdb** lets you execute SQL statement on every database on the instance:

```
declare @cmd varchar(500);
SET @cmd = 'USE ?; SELECT db_name();';
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @cmd;
```

Option 2:
You can also do a similar thing yourself using a cursor over sys.databases. Something like this:

```
declare @cmd2 nvarchar(3000) = 'SELECT db_name();'
declare @cmd1 nvarchar(1000);
declare @cmd nvarchar(4000);
declare @db_name sysname;

declare dbs cursor fast_forward for 
select [name] from sys.databases 
where database_id > 4 
    and state = 0;

OPEN dbs;  

FETCH NEXT FROM dbs INTO @db_name;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN  

    set @cmd1 = 'USE ' + @db_name + ';';
    set @cmd = @cmd1 + @cmd2;
    EXEC sp_executeSQL @cmd;
    FETCH NEXT FROM dbs INTO @db_name;
END 

CLOSE dbs;
DEALLOCATE dbs;
```

Comment: In fact this is really the same option as sp_msforeachdb is just a cursor under the hood. But it will sometimes skip databases. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/